# No package git available on CentOS 5.7

Tags: centos, package-management

After using `yum install git` on my CentOS 5.7 server. It is showing

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
No package git available.
Nothing to do
```

I am very confused; my `git` is not installed on my Linux server.

Comment: Please format the quoted `yum install git` output for better understanding. Also, show us what `yum repolist` says.

Answer (score 2):

End of life for CentOS 5.x : March 31, 2017. Now moved to the museum / the "Vault".
New CentOS 5 repo file, 64bit example, **CentOS-5.11.repo** , copy to /etc/yum.repos.d/ (and remove the other files) :

```
[CentOS-5.11]
name=CentOS-5.11-x86_64 
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[CentOS-5.11-updates]
name=CentOS-5.11-updates-x86_64 
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/updates/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

The package `git` was in the EPEL repo : Not available for EL5 any more.

Comment: After update /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo with 

name=CentOS-5.11-updates-x86_64 
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/updates/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1


Now it is showing below information

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (97, 'Address family not supported by protocol')>
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: CentOS-5.11. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: 1) The file in my answer is a copy of the "CentOS-5.11.repo" file in my 5.11 installs. I made an edit : Both lines with `gpgcheck=1` were changed to **gpgcheck=0** ... 2) Are you sure your OS is 64bits ?

Comment: A) »» Trying other mirror «« : Looks like you forgot to delete / move the obsoleted repo files. B) **git** used to be in the epel.repo : Not valid any more. You can still find `git-1.7.4.x el5` packages at http://rpm.pbone.net/

Answer (score 0):

Git should be in package git-core

```
yum install git-core
```